# Random blue screen of death Windows 7 ntkrnlpa.exe?

Tags: flash, bsod

I have just installed Windows 7 32 bit. I keep having a blue screen of death. So times it happens every other week, some times it happens every other day. I have noticed that it occurs during flash videos more often, however I have noticed it occurring during other applications. I was able to run Prime95 for a good hour and a half. I am able to play games (like tf2 or prototype) without any BSODs. WhoCrashed is saying "ntkrnlpa.exe" for most of the BSODs, but some times is a different process. I have updated my bios. I have tested my ram with MEMTest with no errors. Please take a look at my [dumps](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/643924/Minidump.zip) if you can find something else that I am missing. Thank you very much.

- 9600 nvidia GPU
- 9600 Phenom x4
- Gigabyte MA770UD3 Mobo
- Anything else you need?

Thanks for you time, any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I had another BSOD today, this time evolving win32k.sys. I have preformed chkdsk. Please take a look at [dump](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/643924/121109-17643-01.dmp). Thanks!

Comment: can you give the error of the blue screen. if it automaticly resets you will need to turn that off.Right click on my computer, go to properties, then advance system settings.startup and recovery and uncheck automaticly restart. then when it bsod's tell me the error code.
should say something like "page fault" stop 0x0000051 or other various codes. with that i can trouble shoot the problem.

thanks

Comment: Is that information not in the dump? If not I will do that:)

Comment: the dump has the error but i need to see if its different or the same as i have..it can sometimes change, the error codes..

Comment: it doesn't have the error code im looking for ... and exception code. in any case we can replace that file with one that works...but get me the error code if you can... maybe we can fix the issue without re installing a component

Comment: never mind i found the error codes...i see different ones releated to memory and a sound card(do you have creative sound card?) and yse the ntkrnlpa.exe is there too as well as hal.dll...alot of these are showing me mem problems... check your hard drive...run a diskcheck...if the hard drive is crupting files then it will ALWAYS BSOD...ill read more into it...but give me a update on the codes...if you get anymore...

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I dont think you have to worry about the sound card ones because I had an driver update for that, I like it solved the problem (Arnt those BSOD really old?) I am running a chkdsk /f now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a new computer, you may simply have some bad memory.  Try taking out a stick for a few days (if you have two) and if it still crashes, put the other stick back in and take out the first.

If this is a computer that worked fine with a previous OS, it still could be a bad component, but less likely.  Have you downloaded and installed all the manufacturers drivers, or just used the built-in Windows ones?

EDIT: I think you may have ignored my post because you mentioned running memtest.  Memtest only finds some kinds of errors, so it's not a guarantee your memory is not bad.  Also, Memtest can't find errors that are intermittent.

Heat can be another issue, as well, as flaky power supplies.

Comment: I have ignored your post because I sounds like a scary situation. Because the BSOD's only happen every so often. But I will definitely give it a try. You are just gonnna have to give me some time I just cant believe OCZ would fail me:(  Thanks for the help (I'm also looking in to getting a PSU tester..

Comment: OCZ does fail. Also if memtest is left on overnight it can detect most intermittent memory issues.

Comment: Running Memtest long enough did the trick. I sent my bios settings to Fail Safe and everything worked